# Reversing a linked list, why does head still point to original first element when it should not?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list using the following program. However at the end `head` still mistakenly points to the first element of the original list. Where am I making the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>

struct node{
    node(int val):
        value(val),
        next(nullptr)
    {}

    ~node(){
        delete next;
        std::cout << "Deleting " << value << std::endl;
    }

    int value;
    node* next;
};

node* create()
{
    node * head =  new node(1);
    head->next = new node(2);
    head->next->next = new node(3);
    head->next->next->next = new node(4);
    head->next->next->next->next = new node(5);
    return head;
}

void print(node* head)
{
    auto ptr = head;
    while(ptr !=nullptr)
    {
        std::cout <<  ptr->value << " -> " ;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}

void reverse(node** head_p)
{
    auto head = *head_p;

    auto p2 = head->next;
    head->next = nullptr;

    while(p2!=nullptr)
    {
        auto temp = head;
        head = p2;
        p2 = p2->next;
        head->next = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto head = create();
    print(head);

    reverse(&head);

    print(head);
    delete head;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `delete next;` supposed to do in the destructor of `node`?

Comment: @Lingxi, It deletes the next node.

Comment: [Related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45918/489).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function:

```
void reverse(node** head_p)
{
    auto head = *head_p;

    auto p2 = head->next;
    head->next = nullptr;

    while (p2 != nullptr)
    {
        auto temp = head;
        head = p2;
        p2 = p2->next;
        head->next = temp;
    }
}
```

Unless I read this wrongly, you manipulate the list but fail to update `head_p` which is the pointer to the `head` whose address you passed in.

Comment: I am confused. I am passing the address of the variable. Shouldn't the changes be reflected in the caller program?

Comment: @sank, when you do `auto head = *head_p`, you initialize `head` with the value of the pointer `*head_p` (i.e., the address of the pointer you pass). So `head` is something like `0xA0FF014` (i.e. an address). To modify what's located at that address (i.e., the pointer that you pass by pointer to `reverse`), you need to dereference `head`. Think about how you modify a simple variable passed via a pointer and you'll see what's going on. Or, to simplify things, I suggest to use a `typedef` for `node*`, then your code will become a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your `reverse()` function you are doing `auto head = *head_p;`, but after that you don't modify the pointer `*head_p`. To modify the pointer `*head_p`, you need to dereference `head`, like e.g. `*head = nullptr` (sets what `head` points to to `nullptr`).

Quick fix: replace `auto head` by `auto& head` to use a reference to `*head_p`. Or, better, just pass directly `head` by reference to your `reverse()` function, like

```
void reverse(node*& head_p)
{
    auto p2 = head_p->next;
    head_p->next = nullptr;

    while(p2!=nullptr)
    {
        auto temp = head_p;
        head_p = p2;
        p2 = p2->next;
        head_p->next = temp;
    }
}
```

and invoke it as

```
reverse(head);
```

Comment: I don't think your fix addresses the OP's requirement of "*At the end head still points to the first element of the original list.*"

Comment: @Lingxi I think it works, see [here](http://ideone.com/JMwPsS). The `head` is definitely modified. And I think *"At the end head still points to the first element of the original list."* is the problem, not the requirement :)

Comment: @Lingxi sorry, I don't understand. The OP wants to reverse a linked list, my code is reversing a linked list (that's why I added an extra `reverse(head); print(head);` to see that the list is indeed reversed. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @vsoftco Just a side note here - the temporary variable inside while loop can be eliminated and the loop can be reduced with two swaps: "while(p2!=nullptr) { std::swap (head_p, p2); std::swap (head_p->next, p2); }".

Comment: @NikkiChumakov thanks, you're right, and actually the whole list can be eliminated and use instead `std::list` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think when we have standard library for do somethings we should use them

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std ;

list < int > ls ;

int main()
{
    ls.push_back( 1 ) ;
    ls.push_back( 2 ) ;
    for ( auto x : ls ){
        cout << x << endl ;
    }
    reverse ( ls.begin() , ls.end() ) ;
    for ( auto x : ls ){
        cout << x << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you can use your structure for list for example

```
struct mystruct{
     int a , b ;
     char c ;
};

list < mystruct > ls ;
```

for more information see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)